# Why doesn't the terminal window title change when logging into OpenBSD from Linux Mint?

Tags: bash, linux-mint, ksh, openbsd, window-title

From a Linux Mint terminal window, when I `ssh` into OpenBSD, the terminal window title remains the same as just the terminal `username@localhostname:~`, whereas logging into Ubuntu the terminal window title will change to `username@remotehostname:~`.

I have certainly found *many* solutions to fix this problem, but the solutions seem to be of many different sorts and rarely seem to be addressing the specific shells I am using.

So rather than good ol' "guess-and-check" to figure out which solution is for me, I would prefer to understand why I am having this problem in the first place so I can move to the next step of discovering a solution.

Why doesn't the terminal window title change when using `ssh` to log into OpenBSD with Linux Mint?

Comment: Remote shell on Ubuntu probably uses `OSC P s ; P t BEL`  https://www.xfree86.org/current/ctlseqs.html somewhere.

Comment: Show output of `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND`, let's see.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk It prints a blank line.

Comment: are you talking about the command prompt?

Comment: @jsotola some graphical terminal emulators, running in a GUI, have a title on the top of their window. I think that is what the OP wants to see changing. Apparently, some Ubuntu systems issue a command changing that title, I have never seen this myself.

Comment: @Paul why do you need something specific to your shell? If you have found solutions to the "problem", why not use them?

Comment: @terdon that function may be DM specific

Comment: @Paul it seems that your question is somewhat of an XY question ... you are asking `why doesn't...?` when you actually want to know `how to ...?`

Comment: @terdon Because I would just be copying and pasting to see if it works. The solutions provide little-to-no explanation as to why this is a problem and are answers to questions with different shells on either or both ends. IOW, I haven't found a solution to my problem, but I have found many solutions to other problems that may solve my problem but I can't define in more precise terms what my problem is, so I can't figure out which solution is the one to solve my problem.

Comment: @jsotola I am trying to solve one problem, which is that I don't understand why this is occurring. If you can find an answer to the problem, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

After a terminal window is created, its title only changes when some program within the window outputs a certain series of characters.  For xterm windows, this series of characters is `<ESC>]0;title goes here<BEL>`, though it seems other sequences are also supported.

Presumably, the shell on your Ubuntu system is configured to emit this sequence, most likely as an invisible part of the command prompt.  If you're using bash, the configuration telling bash to do this would tend to be located in your `~/.bashrc` file, which would have been created from an Ubuntu-supplied default when you created your account on the system.

Your shell on your OpenBSD system, on the other hand, apparently came with no such default configuation, and so, when you are logged into the system, there is nothing telling the running terminal to change its title.

Comment: I searched through `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, and `/etc/bash.bashrc`, and none have `ESC` or `BEL`. In `~/.bashrc` I do have `# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir \ case "$TERM" in \ xterm*|rxvt*)`. (Although Mint uses `gnome-terminal`.)

Comment: @Paul: Yes, it'd be that block in your `~/.bashrc`, but with `ESC` and `BEL` written as `\e` and `\a`.